# A tricky question of simple Java: variable scope

Tags: java

I am not new to java and C#. I thought I understand the concept of variable scope until recently I was asked this question in an interview:

```
public class Q{ //starting y scope

    static int x = 11;
    private int y = 33; // Just added a “private” modifier to make it clearer.

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Q q = new Q();
        q.call(5);
    }

    public void call(int x){
        Q q = new Q();

        this.x = 22;
        y = 44;

        System.out.println("Output: " + Q.x);
        System.out.println("Output: " + q.x);
        System.out.println("Output: " + q.y);
    }

} //ending y scope
```

Define the output of this program.

I answered the question during the interview that the output would be a runtime exception. To my understanding, y is declared private, and the instance method call() is trying to access the instance private variable y of another instance of class Q. How could that happen at all!? However answering this question wrongly didn't affect my interview too much because this is the kind of "tricky basic" question. But, answering wrongly means my years' Java experience needs rehab, that's terrible!

Could someone help me on this matter? I would be so much appreciated!

Comment: Does it output 11,22,33?

Comment: Not quite sure how this is a "tricky" question.

Comment: I would say 22, 22, 33, `x` is static, so why couldn't it be changed by `this.x = 22` ?

Comment: I would call this basic question rather than tricky one

Comment: It's tricky for me though! And I think regardless of your programming experience it's always those "really basic" problems that get you stuck as generally you wouldn't bother think of them. :p

Comment: BTW, the output is 22, 22, 33. this.x changes the static field x of the class, instead of the argument passed by this function, y = 44 simply does nothing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can access `private` members of your own class, even from a different instance of the class.

Comment: +1 if you couldn't then it would be nigh on impossible to implement `Comparable`.

Comment: @Qwerky: You assume people properly code variables as private :)

Comment: @SLaks, +1: access modifiers control which classes/packages have access, not which instances have access.

Comment: ... and that is the right thing from the point of view of encapsulation. The code knows the internal representation of instances, so it can access it for all of them.

Comment: @Slaks, @Peter Lawrey Thank you! I think that's the correct way to express the answer. I think it's always required to define a Getter and Setter for the private field of a class. Hence, I have never thought the difference between access a private field from an instance of the class within the class or from an instance of the class in other classes.

Comment: Private to the class, not private to the instance.  I did not know that before now.

Answer (score 8):

`private` just means it can't be accessed by objects of *another* class, not *any* other objects.  So one `Q` object can access the private members of another `Q` object.

[*Note that if this were illegal, this would trigger a compiler error, not a runtime exception.*]

Answer (score 6):

Private variables are accessible within the *program text* of the declaring class. It doesn't matter if one instance tries to access variables in another instance, so long as the code is within the same class.

From the [JLS section 6.6](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6):

> Otherwise, if the member or constructor is declared private, then access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.

Comment: Thanks!! The link you shared really helps

Answer (score 3):

`private` means that classes outside of this class cannot see the variable. Within this class definition, all methods and variables can be accessed.

Answer (score 3):

Access restrictions should be enforced compile time not in run time, so the compiler should prevent compiling the code if it was wrong.

But an access modifier is applied on class level, so you can always access a private member from the class it self.

When you clone an object this is often useful since you can just set a bunch of values in the clone directly, which might have been hard to access otherwise. Also when comparing objects with an Equals method it can be quite handy that it is the class not the instance that defines the access restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

As it was already pointed out, private members of the other instances are accessible from the class. Also, you were incorrect about the runtime exception: there will be no runtime exception even if you modify the code so that you try to access a private member of another class, the code will just fail to compile.

Answer (score 2):

I think there will be a compilation problem because the attribute `static int x = 11` is declared static and in the method `call`, the variable x is accessed by a `this`. You cannot make a `this` to a static variable in a class.

There is no problem with the private member `y`.

Comment: "You cannot make a this to a static variable in a class." Why not??? You can use "this" keyword to access any variable or method inside a class, no matter what modifiers it has.

Comment: As Filipe said, it is possible. However, it is not recommended and will yield a compiler warning.

Comment: Yeah, I went to read again the spec and tried some testing. I was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The correct "interview" answer is that whoever wrote code like this should be fired! Lousy class name, useless comments about y scope; non-standard use of "this" which should really only be used for instance variables, not class variables; re-using 'q' in the main and call methods.

It reminds me of the obfuscated C++ contests, exactly the sort of nonsense Java was designed to avoid.

Worse than this, though, is that it's very difficult to tell from the comments and the answers what the output of the program should be. Do I go by the '6' on the comment by Kevin?

I wish an admin would refactor all this. And I would tell an interviewer (if this really is an interview question, which I doubt) that we should run the code, get the answers, and then create a simple test to confirm that the answers don't change when we refactor the code to conform to standard usage.

Comment: The point of interview questions is: how well do you know what java will do before you run it?  It is a lot faster and cheaper to write functioning code when you don't need to call in an "admin" to give you the answers.  If your answer in an interview is call in an "admin" then my next question is "why should I pay you instead of just paying the admin?"

Comment: This really was an interview question, they purposefully made this class looks like that. After almost one year when I look back at this question again (thanks to you Ed for commenting now) I realize that this question doesn't make too much sense as for the last year of being a real programmer I almost have never used Java in this way. But yes @mwengler, the point of the question was just testing how well you know java and obviously I didn't know java that well a year ago :p